# Wrote a Future method where Testcoverage is not 100%

Tags: apex, code-coverage, future

Testcoverage class :

```
@isTest
public class AccountCalcultorTest {
    @isTest
    public static void contactcalculatorTest(){
        List<Account> accAdd = new List<Account>();
        
        for(Integer i=0; i < 250; i++){
            accAdd.add(new Account(Name = 'Test'+i));
        }
        
        List<contact> conList = new List<contact>();
        List<id> conID = new List<id>();
        
        for(Account acc : accAdd){
            conList.add(new Contact(FirstName = 'Test', LastName = acc.Name, AccountId = acc.Id));
            conID.add(acc.Id);
        }

        insert conList;
        
        System.Test.startTest();
        Testing.ContactCalculator(conID);
        System.Test.stopTest();
        
        List<account> accss = [select id, NoOfContacts__c from account];
    }
}
```

Future class:

```
public class Testing {
    @future
    public static void ContactCalculator(List<Id> accID){
        
        List<Account> Acclist = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM CONTACTS) FROM ACCOUNT WHERE Id IN :accID];
        
        System.debug('Point 1' + Acclist);
        
        for(Account acc : Acclist){
            acc.NoOfContacts__c = acc.Contacts.size();
            System.debug('1');
        }
        
        if(!Acclist.isEmpty()){
            update Acclist;
            System.debug('2');
        }
        
        for(Account accs : Acclist){
            System.debug('point 2: ' + accs.NoOfContacts__C);
        }        
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, without any asserts, the "unit test" has little value and cannot really be called a test.

Comment: the account records in the accAdd list never has an account Id. You need to insert accAdd so that when you loop over the list and populate the conID list, you have an account id